# Filling up data in tidyverse with a smart loop

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the following data:

```
AT <- tibble(Year = c(2015,2015, 2017,2017),G = c("A","B", "A", "B"), A =c(1,2,2,3), B = c(3,4,5,6)) %>%
```

arrange(G)

It contains data for the years 2015 and 2017. I want to use these data to "generate" data for the years 2014, 2016, 2017, and 2019, where the data has to be taken from the first following year that has data only from the previous year in 2019.

Any idea how to do this in a smart way? I tried with loops, but couldn't manage.

Cheers

Renger

Answer (score 1):

May be we can use `complete` with `fill`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
AT %>%
   complete(Year = 2014:2019) %>% 
   fill(G, A, B, .direction = 'updown')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint. I used a loop to get it to work

```
AT <- tibble(Year = c(2015,2015, 2017,2017), 
             G = c("A","B", "A", "B"), 
             A =c(1,2,2,3), 
             B = c(3,4,5,6)) %>% arrange(G)

ATC<-   AT %>% 
   complete(Year = 2014:2019, G = c("A","B")) 
ATC2 <- AT %>% slice(0) # empty tibble

for (i in unique(AT$G)) {
    ATP <- ATC %>%  
    filter(G == i) %>% 
    fill(A,B,.direction = 'updown') 
    ATC2 <- rbind(ATC2, ATP)
 }
```